# Series, limits and convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Can you help me with it with working

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\cos \left(\frac{2n+1}{n^2+n}\right)\sin \left(\frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)$

I am struck in the part where i get,

$\lim _{n\to \infty \:\:}\left(n\left(\frac{\cos \left(\frac{2n+1}{n^2+n}\right)\sin \left(\frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)}{\cos \left(\frac{2\left(n+1\right)+1}{\left(n+1\right)^2+n+1}\right)\sin \left(\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)^2+n+1}\right)}-1\right)\right)$

this expression

Comment: Welcome. Try to explain in your question what you have already tried, and where exactly you got stuck. On this website, people aren't looking to do your homework for you, or to just give you answers. We're here to help you understand concepts and problems, and we can only do that if you show us your input.

Comment: for the 5.1 - i get 0, so converges

Comment: for 5.2 - i get 2 , by raabe's test it converges

Comment: for 5.3 - i get 1/3, by ratio test it converges

Comment: for 5.4 - i'm struck. i tried direct comparison test

Comment: @Dudley You should ask a question at time and write down a full answer here using MathJax.

Comment: Using the text given here $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}$$ which you can copy and past try to write the question in a proper way and show your work on that. Refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\cos \left(\frac{2n+1}{n^2+n}\right)\sin \left(\frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)$  @gimusi sorry for not using it in the first go

Comment: @Dudley That's nice, let edit your question and add that with some explanation on your try. In that way of course you'll receive some help and/or hint on that.

Comment: @gimusi can you see it now ?

Comment: @Dudley Therefore your doubt was only on that one?

Comment: @gimusi yes, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Dudley I've added something on that. You are interested only to determine whether it converges or not? You should also specify that in your question.

Comment: @gimusi both infact, when i solved it I got 2 and by Raabe's test its convergent right ?

Comment: @Dudley You could refer to limit comparison test, it is really more conventient here.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

For the first one

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+2-1}{(n+2)!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+2)!}$$

then recall that

$$e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$$

For the one presented after editing note that since $\frac{2n+1}{n^2+n}\to 0 $ and $\frac{1}{n^2+n}\to 0$ we have

$$\cos \left(\frac{2n+1}{n^2+n}\right)\sin \left(\frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)\sim1\cdot\frac{1}{n^2+n}$$

Answer (score 0):

For large enough $n$ we have $$0<\cos \left({2n+1\over n^2+n}\right)\sin \left({1\over n^2+n}\right)<1\times {1\over n^2+n}={{1\over n^2+n}}$$therefore the series converges using Squeeze theorem.